# How can I fix my terminal when editing the PATH in .bash_profile has the startup hang and I get no prompt?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, path

I am new to the command line and clearly messed up my setup.

- macOS High Sierra(10.13.6)
- Trying to set up Python and VScode.

My path variable is what I believe is wrong, but Idon't know exactly how to get a shell and fix things.

It is now showing the user name when i go into terminal. After trying everything i tried to follow. https://shellzero.wordpress.com/tag/reset-path-on-mac/
My Terminal now looks like this[image: Terminal]

My bash profile currently looks like this  when i enter `open .bash_profile` in new command on terminal[image: bash_profile text file]

according to the suggestion of the article mentioned above, after entering `export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin` and save the text file by `command+S`
I tried to execute `source ~/.bash_profile` in new command in terminal and the result was [image: bash_profile after source command]

After that i also run the command `echo $PATH.` and the result was this :[image: bash_profile after echo $PATH. Command]

I have no idea what i did. And what i need to do to fix the problem. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any shells still working? The quick fix would be to move / delete / rename the file you edited. It has a syntax error that's blocking the startup. If not, we'll see what the next steps are like make a new admin account should you have none and then get control again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK - no worries. You did in fact mess things up, but here's an easy way to fix things.

- Open TextEdit (or whatever editor you like graphically on the Mac)
- Open a file and go to your home folder (click or press Command Shift G and type ~ and return)
- Show hidden files (if needed) - Command + Shift + .
- Open .bash_profile

Delete everything or comment out anything that contains PATH= and save the file (you can save as to save it to your Desktop if you want to fix it up rather than start new).

Then open a new terminal window to check your work. If it works, close out the broken sessions and make sure you incorporate the old path when you add things:

This is safe:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH:/path/to/whatever/bin"
```

It's safe since the old $PATH is included on the right of the =

What isn't safe is when

```
export PATH="whatever"
```

All the other parts of the path are now gone, with only **whatever** left and the last = wins, so your path is missing very important items instead of adding things to the default path, you broke it temporarily. No worries, this is a phase of passage - everyone needs to break their shell dot files to learn. Welcome to the club.

Comment: Thanks bmike.i will try to do that. My bash_profile has so so many stuff.IT will be tuff. BTW where should i put the new  "export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin" in bash_profile? In the begining or in the end?

Comment: my bash_profile is filled with so many code with PATH=".....'
is it possible that i delete everything except the new line "export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin""

Comment: It's also critical that you remove from the `cat << EOF ...` line through the `EOF` on a line by itself -- every time that runs, it adds another batch of garbled mess to the end of the .bash_profile itself. Frankly, I think it'll be easier to dump it, and start over (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend a somewhat different approach from @bmike: rather than trying to remove the bad parts from the current file, start over and add back just the good parts. It looks like there's a lot more bad than good in the current file, so this should be simpler.

What's really *really* **really** bad in the current file is the section that starts like this:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
```

...and somewhere down below that there'll be `EOF` alone on a line. The problem is that this isn't an instruction to set up your environment, it's instructions to *add instructions to your ~/.bash_profile*. In other words, every time your ~/.bash_profile runs, it adds another copy of the stuff between `cat` and `EOF` to the end of ~/.bash_profile, so the file gets longer and longer and longer... and has more and more copies of the messed up instructions.

At this point, your ~/.bash_profile will be huge, and mostly garbled nonsense.

So, I recommend starting over. Rename and save the current file, so you can refer back to it if necessary, then create a new blank .bash_profile in your home directory. I recommend [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) for this -- it has a free demo mode that'll do everything you need here, and (unlike most text editors) it won't do "helpful" things like converting plain ASCII quotes (like `"`) to fancy unicode quotes (like `“` and `”`) that mess up shell scripts. It also doesn't complain about saving files with names that start with ".".

From the section visible in your screenshot, this is the only part of the current file that looks right:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

There might be something you actually want further down, but since the `cat` part starts shortly after that I doubt it. In any case, this should be enough to get you a basically functional setup; if there are some things that still don't work, you may have to look through the old file for other things that need salvaging.

Comment: I Have billions of code in the bash_profile.So it vary hard for me to pick & Choose. Moreover i already uninstall and deleted python3,VScode. I was wondering if i delete everything on bash and just keep this one line code "export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin" in th bash_profile. is it posiible to fix the issue? i am in real urgency.so fixing this thing quick is a big deal. later i can reinstall all the programs which should be fine? Thanks a lot again.I really Really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you still using Visual Studio Code? If so, I'd keep just the last two lines of what I have above. If you're not using VS Code, just remove the .bash_profile entirely (but keep a backup, just in case). `PATH` should be automatically set to a reasonable (but basic) value without the file. If you do need to set it for some reason, `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` is the original default, and I'd recommend using that.

Comment: I just deleted everything and just kept the line "export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin" 
now seems like the terminal running again. I Just got this back:
[braeburn:~ [username]$ echo $PATH.
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin.]

Comment: That's pretty close to the standard `PATH`, but it's missing `/usr/local/bin`. I'd recommend either removing that line (leaving the default `PATH`), or force the standard value with `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: BTW i removed my previous SQL path [export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"], If i want to add it again to my bash_profile (otherwise MYSQL dont run for some reason) what should be the safe code?

Comment: Thanks. I already changed the path according to your recommendation. if you have time and can tell me how i can add the SQL code safe into bash_profile given that i deleted [export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"], i would be truly grateful.
BTW applying your suggestion my new path is now [/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Comment: Adding `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"` to your .bash_profile is fine. As bmike said in his answer, it's the entries that don't include `$PATH` on the right side that cause problems. Essentially, an entry like this *adds to* the `PATH`, while one that doesn't have `$PATH` on the right side is *replacing* the `PATH` (deleting all the other additions that're already there). Adding things to `PATH` just increases the list of places the system will look for command files, which isn't a big deal.

Comment: Amazingly well done Gordon. I didn’t conceive of the `cat` and that explains much of the mess. Thanks for reinforcing - just set it aside, add pieces in little by little. Also BBEdit - ♥️ that program so much