# Process completed immediately after opening Terminal and impossible to add commands

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Since I have made some changes on my .bash_profile document, when I open my terminal I got this message and I cannot add any command :

```
Last login: Thu Dec 19 10:02:58 on ttys000

[Process completed]
```

After trying many things like changing back my bash_profile to what it used to be but nothing worked. I spent a whole day on it. I followed this from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296871/313842 :

> 1. Go to Terminal icon on Dock, press right click and press New Command
> 2. `/bin/bash -x` , and reopen Terminal (it shows your problem)
> 3. Go to Preferences → General and set Shells open with to Command, and enter the following: `/bin/sh`
> 4. Close the Terminal Preferences window
> 5. Open Terminal again (it should work)
> 6. `vi /Users/<your_user>/.bash_profile`, remove the lines found in step 2
> 7. Go to Preferences → General and set Shells open with to Command, and enter the following: `/bin/bash`
> 8. Open Terminal, it should work now

Current issue : When I try step 6, I do not find the 2 lines and if I set Shells back to `/bin/bash`, it shows the original error again :

```
Last login: Thu Dec 19 10:10:32 on ttys000

[Process completed]
```

Here is the content of .bash_profile:

```
# Enable tab completion
source ~/git-completion.bash

# colors!
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"
```

You can find the content of the sourced files on these links: 
 - git-completion.bash : https://pastebin.com/Y1X6FdNW
 - git-prompt.sh : https://pastebin.com/zt2pyLce

After bash -l :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-apple:~ apple$ bash -l
Segmentation fault: 11
MacBook-Pro-de-apple:~ apple$
```

Comment: What is the problem shown in step 2? Which two lines do you miss in step 6?

Comment: [How can I fix my terminal when editing the PATH in .bash_profile has the startup hang and I get no prompt?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351000/how-can-i-fix-my-terminal-when-editing-the-path-in-bash-profile-has-the-startup?rq=1)

Comment: Hi @nohillside, it actually didn't show anything for me on step 2. The instructions I found on that link (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153408/process-completed-immediately-after-opening-terminal/296871#296871) said that I would have to delete the lines found on step 2 but I can't find them...

Comment: @klanomath I realized my bash_profile content is already in my question. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @klanomath ! I am not familiar with all of this (sorry). Could you please tell me where can I find the sourced .bash or .sh git related files ?

Comment: Both of these files are in your home directory.

Comment: Do you have any output on the screen when starting the shell after step 2? If yes, please copy/paste that directly into your question.

Comment: @nohillside Actually when I reopen the terminal, I have no specific output.

Comment: These are two huge files, uhh. To narrow it down, can you please add `#` in front of both of the `source` lines in your `.bash_profile` and repeat step 7 & 8. If it works, remove it from one of the lines again and repeat 7/8. Goal is to figure out which of the `source` commands triggers the problem.

Comment: @klanomath I modified line 307 to `p[\ \ ]|pick[\ \ ]*)` and repeated steps 7 and 8, no change.

@nohillside It did not work. as long as I do step 7 and 8 the problem persists. Only step 3 allows me to access my terminal correctly. I am not familiar at all with all of this so thanks for your patience to both of you

Comment: Look, if you add a `#` in front of both lines starting with `source` and you still get the same issue after step 7 and 8 the problem is *not* in the huge files you've put to pastebin. Can you please make sure the `#` are there and then (without doing steps 7 and 8) just run `bash -l` in the still open Terminal window? Afterwards copy/paste any output between `bash -l` and the next prompt.

Comment: @nohillside I got this error : "Segmentation fault: 11". What does that mean ?

Comment: Something crashed. Please copy/paste the whole thing into your question to make sure we don't miss anything. Also, are you sure you are showing your whole .bash_profile in the question?

Comment: @nohillside yes I am sure I am pasting the whole .bash_profile doc. I really don't know what's going on...

Comment: Can you do `mv .bash_profile .bash_profile_bak` (so `bash` doesn't read it anymore) and run `bash -l` again?

Comment: @klanomath Please post the answer afterwards :-)

Comment: @klanomath In that case telling the OP to copy/paste their .bash_profile from the question back into the file itself should work :-)

Answer (score 2):

Problem fixed after following this:

1. Go to Terminal Preferences > Open Shells with : enter "/bin/bash -x"
2. On the terminal :  nano .bash_profile
3. Delete the whole content of the bash_profile, then Ctrl + X (exit) Yes, Enter
4. Go to Terminal Preferences > Open Shells with : enter "/bin/bash"

someone guided me to that. For some reason, my .bash_profile was kind of doing a loop...
Apparently, I also had another bash_profile document somewhere else...
I won't be able to give more details for now as the person left but I will add more info here once I got them. Hope this will help others.

Thanks a lot to @nohillside and @klanomath for your help!! I appreciate a lot.